# SSH Connections Refused When Routing Through Xinetd

Tags: ssh, xinetd

I'm trying to route SSH connections from port 22 on the SSH machine to port 2222 on the xinetd machine, I get a connection refused error every time I try to connect through port 2222 on the xinetd machine.
The SSH machine is running CentOS 5.4 and the xinetd machine is also running CentOS 5.4.

Xinetd service:

```
service 2222
{
socket_type = stream
port = 2222
wait = no
user = root
redirect = 10.10.10.10 22
}
```

And the Terminal output on my Mac:

```
Mac mini:~ Justin$ ssh -v root@sub.mydomain.com -p 2222
OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8l 5 Nov 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to sub.mydomain.com [xxx.22.xxx.29] port 2222.
debug1: connect to address xxx.22.xxx.29 port 2222: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host sub.mydomain.com port 2222: Connection refused
Mac mini:~ Justin$
```

Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you connect to 10.10.10.10:2222 from the xinetd machine? If you can, check you're not denying packets on the xinetd machine in the FORWARD chain of IPTables

Comment: I am trying to connect to 10.10.10.10:22 in the SSH machine and be able to access that from the xinetd machine from port 2222 since the xinetd machine also runs SSH, I would like to be able to connect to the xinetd machine on port 2222 to access 10.10.10.10:22